# Magento- How to integrate affiliated product to our site

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am new to magento, i am trying to display amazon product in my website, like affiliate marketing. i have no idea for how to do this. can anyone guide me how to display the affiliated product to my website..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do it like you do it with every other site, open up a template and paste in your affiliate tracking code you get from Amazon.